# How to make Fragment + Firebase firestore work without leaking resources(in Android)?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

One way to retrieve a document from firestore is using [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) API.

I am woking with a Fragment that displays some data fetched from firestore, as this fragment is shown upon a user action I want a document fetching `Task` to only work in between fragment's life-cycle methods `onAttach()` and `onDetach()`.

If `onDetach()` is called and document is still in process on being retrieved from firestore I want **it to stop** as it would consume resources unnecessarily.

The `Task` API itself has a [provision](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/CancellationToken) to be cancelled but it appear to me that firestore SDK does not provide that functionality (although there is a [convenient method](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks#activity-scoped_listeners) for scoping that only works with activities in limited manner).

How do I use `Task` API in this case so it does not leak resources? 
Should I go with document [snapshot listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) instead which provides the functionality to remove listeners?

I would like to mention that if I go with snapshot listener way I lose benefits of Task APIs which allows me to cascade post processing methods using [continuation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Continuation)(bit like RxAndroid).

Any help appreciated.

p.s. I have read this series of [blogs](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-1.html), it shades light on the issue but it does not provide any solution for the scenario I have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, there is no way to cancel the Task of a Firestore query.

If you want to resume the observation of the results of a Task after a configuration change, you can retain it in your ViewModel (or whatever you use to retain state between configuration changes), then attach a new listener to it in the new Fragment/Activity.  That will get you a long way toward a memory-efficient use of a Task.

You would have to try VERY hard to actually leak significant memory this way.  I have never heard of a crash due to the leak of a Firestore query that didn't complete.  The Firestore SDK is in control over its own memory use in that respect, and there's actually nothing you can do to force it to free up memory if you don't want the results of some query.  Trying to do so, without a specific problem at hand, could be considered a form of "premature optimization".

If you're not satisfied with this, please [file a feature request](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/tree/master/firebase-firestore) with the SDK directly.

Comment: You should not pass a listener to a Task that holds a strong reference to an Activity or Fragment.  Usually one abstracts this away (as you can guess) with a LiveData object that can have observers added and removed from it.  I will note that you are digging deep into Android architecture patterns, and it's out of scope to fully discuss all the options and the ramifications they have on your app.